# Menú activo al ser elegido

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

estoy desarrollando un sitio web, y tengo problemas con el menú, quisiera que la opción elegida se quede activa; he intentado varias cosas con js, funciona cuando se coloca ahref="#"; pero cuando le añado una página distinta, no funciona; he podido detectar que (disculpe la ignorancia al respecto) el jscript se vuelve a ejecutar cuando se da clic a algún enlace por lo que toma como activo el enlace por defecto.
Ya probé quitando el valor activo al  correspondiente valor (li); y sigue sin funcionar.

Este es el código en mención, el cual lo encontré en Internet

```
        <ul class="sidemenu" id="sidemenu">
            <li id="index" class="active"><a href="index">Inicio</a></li>
            <li id="privacy"><a href="/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inscribirse a Curso</a></li>
        </ul>
```

JS

```
  $('.sidemenu li').on('click', function () {
   $('li.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
});`
```

CSS

```
    .active {
    background-color: #A0A0A0;
    }`
```

El proceso es el siguiente cuando se selecciona el menú, entonces toma inicialmente el link elegido, luego al cargar el destino; vuelve a cargar la cabecera donde están los menús; y el activo vuelve ser el por defecto; y ese queda resaltado.

PD. Estoy usando los archivos _layout.cshtml, site.css y site.js

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que algo asi te puede servir:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-swirles-r9cje

```js
// Obtienes todos los links del menu con la clase .sidemenu
var items = document.querySelectorAll(".sidemenu__item a");

// Recorres cada uno de los links
items.forEach(function(item) {
  // Si la url del link es igual a la url actual del navegador
  // entonces a ese link se le coloca la clase .active
  if (item.href === document.URL) {
    item.className = "active";
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
}

a.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sidemenu">
  <li class="sidemenu__item">
    <a href="/">Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sidemenu__item">
    <a href="/privacy">Privacy</a>
  </li>
  <li class="sidemenu__item">
    <a href="/inscribirse-curso">Inscribirse a Curso</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sí, me ayuda bastante, porque la respuesta resalta la selección hecha, ya el fondo de la selección hecha, si lo quiero cambiar, ya no es complicado; la idea es que funciona de acuerdo a lo que necesito. Muchas gracias.